# How can I recover a dropped table which is not in the recycle bin?

Tags: oracle, linux, oracle-11g

I dropped a table yesterday and I want to restore it. I know that it's done with flashback but the table is not present in the recycle bin (*yes* it is set as ON).

So how can I restore a table that is not in the recycle bin. I am logged in as `sysdba` and also there are no rows neither in the `dba_recyclebin` nor in the `user_recyclebin`.

Comment: Restore from your backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone your production database to a point in time before the table was dropped, then export the table you need and import into your prod database. 
You can also try a table space point in time recovery. I tested it out a few years back, but I haven't needed to do it since.

[Performing RMAN Tablespace Point-in-Time Recovery (TSPITR)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmtspit.htm#BRADV89795)